# snmpwalk via php gives error 500, but is correct output when "php + file" commandline

Tags: php, snmp

I need to check the OperStatus on a Cisco switch via SNMP.

I'm using PHP scripts running on a CentOS server. With command-line everything works, e.g.
  `snmpwalk -v 2c -c XXXXcommunityXXXX XXXXIPXXXX XXXOIDXXX` gives me the expected output.

Now with PHP, I use the function `snmpwalk()`  to try and get the same output:

```
$ip = "XXX";
$community = "XXX";
//$obj = "XXX";
$obj = "IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.10002";

    $output =  snmpwalk($ip, $community, $obj);
    var_dump($output);
```

The script works as expected when I'm connected on the server and type `php +filename.php` but not when I try to display the php file via chrome it just give me an error 500.

Any ideas?

Comment: look at your server's error log for details about the 500. there's no point in trying to GUESS what the problem might be until you have more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but the snmp module for php was not loaded, i don't know why it worked with command line though.

I just had to reboot my server and it was done.